# phonegap app working fine in emulator but not in mobile

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, emulation

I have done my app in phonegap. My app is working fine on emulatoor but not working on android phone after the apk is done. I am having googlemaps as the app. What changes should i have to do while installing on the phone or any measures to solve it.?

Comment: Please elaborate on 'not working'. Also, are any errors reported in the console (in Eclipse or in Chrome's chrome:inspect)?

Comment: Connect your phone and debug.

Comment: how to debug? i should open my apk in eclipse or what? i am new to android/phonegap. Please elaborate on it.

Comment: if you don't have a modern device, which allows remote debug naturally:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

try using "Weinre"

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/